# how to solve the REST Client response "The connection was rejected"

Tags: visual-studio-code, rest-client

I am debugging php code with VS Code.

My launch configuration works perfectly, I can launch and debug my code. I can launch, break, inspect, and resume my code, when opening the `http://localhost:8000/test.php` URL on the browser.

**However**, the same server does not get invoked when trying to open the very same `http://localhost:8000/test.php` URL using the REST Client.

a very simple "test.http" containing just

```
###
GET http://localhost:8000
Accept: application/json
```

on pressing the "Send Request" prompt it just does respond with the error message

> The connection was rejected. Either the requested service isn’t
> running on the requested server/port, the proxy settings in vscode are
> misconfigured, or a firewall is blocking requests. Details:
> RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000.

But, the server *is* running; the very same URL works perfectly on the browser and with curl.

```bash
XXXX@XXXXX MINGW64 ~/Documents/projects/fgplat (master)
$ curl localhost:8000

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
....
```

A single image tells the problem
[image: screen capture of vscode]

(1) The PHP server is running
(2) and (3) curl at windows and bash terminals in vscode are ok
(4) and (5) request from rest client is not

There is no firewall configured. The same URL opens on the browser and with curl.

I have tried curl from both the windows command prompt and bash terminal, either from the vscode integrated terminal or from an open external terminal. All the cases open the url correctly.

I have tried changing the port, tried 8000 8080 and 6543, exactly the same problem with REST client refusing connection; and obviously all ports work with curl or browser.

REST client and vsCode have no proxy configured.

What am I missing? Any idea on how to solve (or at least how to debug) this apparently simple problem?

Comment: Hi @PA. Your error message seems to be incomplete. There might be something else after the service isn't running. 
Anyways, you can try below two commands for debugging purposes:
curl -v http://localhost:8000/test.php
telnet localhost 8000

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried your suggested alternatives. They worked.  The server does respond to curl, the same way it does to the browser. It just seems to ignore rest client.

Comment: Ok. You may check to see if any proxy is to be configured in your REST client, or perhaps, something like the below might resolve your issue: http://localhost:8000/test.php?proxyHost=application-proxy.corp.dmz&proxyPort=8080

Comment: responding your comment up in the post for completing the question.

Comment: hi @PA would you be able to retry with a different port like 8080 and test it to see if port 8000 has issue.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Changin the port makes no difference.